# Can I get a DateTime if the month is a word?

Tags: delphi, datetime, delphi-xe7

I've populated a ComboBox with months and years in the format:

```
August 2014
July 2014
June 2014
```

On selection (let's say July 2014), I would ideally like to create a DateTime variable in the format '01/07/14'. Is there a way of taking a month that is presently a string and converting into an integer?

Many thanks for your time.

Comment: Yes, there are ways to do this

Comment: At the moment I intend to split the string by the space to give me 'July' and '2014', then iterate through LongMonthNames until I hit a match on the month. Just checking if there was a more efficient way.

Comment: From what you have posted, it looks like there are no more efficient ways. It is hard to tell without seeing the actual code populating your ComboBox.

Comment: Indead you need to split this string and get the month in word format.
Then you can encode the date into a TDateTime format.

I sugest you read the System.DateUtils unit, its VERY helpful and you will understand once for all how TDateTime works, along with knowing a lot of useful date and time funcions.

Comment: You could use a TDictionary<String, Integer>. Efficient is a matter opinion.

Comment: How many entries you have in your ComboBox? Do all entries follow each other? If they do all you need to do is figure out which one is the first entry and then use simple math to decode rest from the item index. Each year has 12 months so if the first item is Januarry 2014 you can extract yeary by simply dividing the index with 12. And to retrieve which monthy you calculate modulus result.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way of taking a month that is presently a string and converting into an integer?

Yes. Loop over the possible names looking for a match:

```
function GetMonthNumber(const fs: TFormatSettings; const Name: string): Integer;
begin
  for Result := Low(fs.LongMonthNames) to High(fs.LongMonthNames) do
    if SameText(Name, fs.LongMonthNames[Result]) then
      exit;
  Result := -1;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my simple example how to get month number.

```
const
 Month : array [1..12] of string = ('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');

function TForm1.IndexOfMonth(s: string): integer;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  result := -1;
  for I := 1 to 12 do
    begin
      if UpperCase(S) = UpperCase(Month[i]) then
       begin
         result := i;
         break;
       end;
    end;
end;

function TForm1.GetMonthFromCombo : integer;
var s : string;
begin
  s := Copy(ComboBox1.Text,1, Pos(' ', ComboBox1.Text)-1);
  result := IndexOfMonth(s);
end;
```

Comment: Some problems with this. First of all, the function should not be a method of a form. That's the wrong level for it. Secondly, the function does not always set the return value. Thirdly, you are repeating month names rather than using built in values. Fourthly, your comparison is case sensitive. It's not obvious what your answer adds beyond the answer that Zam wrote.

Comment: This is just an example. For this purpose it is no matter whether this is a method or function. You are wright about case sensitive. I also added returning result. About Zam's answer I did'n see it. i'm sorry.

Comment: It really does matter whether this is a method of a form, or exposed in a reusable way. By making it a method of a form you are presenting an example to a developer who clearly is still learning. If the developer follows your example then they will be learning bad practise.